# Magento 2 get order in custom block

Tags: magento2

I have a custom module which sends email to custom email address after successful purchase. It works well but now I need to get gift message from order.

Here is my Block code

```php
<?php

namespace Test\Test2\Block\Vendor\Shipment;

class Items extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    const DEFAULT_TYPE = 'default';

    public function getItemRenderer($type)
    {
        /** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList $rendererList */
        $rendererList = $this->getRendererListName() ? $this->getLayout()->getBlock($this->getRendererListName()) : $this->getChildBlock('renderer.list');
        if (!$rendererList) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Renderer list for block "' . $this->getNameInLayout() . '" is not defined');
        }
        $overriddenTemplates = $this->getOverriddenTemplates() ?: [];
        $template = isset($overriddenTemplates[$type]) ? $overriddenTemplates[$type] : $this->getRendererTemplate();
        $renderer = $rendererList->getRenderer($type, self::DEFAULT_TYPE, $template);
        $renderer->setRenderedBlock($this);
        return $renderer;
    }

    public function getItemHtml(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $item)
    {
        $block = $this->getItemRenderer($item->getProductType())->setItem($item);
        return $block->toHtml();
    }
}
```

and email template .phtml

```php
<?php $_items = $block->getItems() ?>
<?php $_order = $block->getOrder() ?>
<?php if ($_items): ?>
    <table class="items email-items shipment-items order-items">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class="item-info">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Items'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-price">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Price'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="item-qty">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Qty'); ?>
                </th>
                <th class="row-total">
                    <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Total'); ?>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <?php foreach ($_items as $_item): ?>
            <?php
                if ($_item->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
            ?>
            <tbody>
                <?= $block->getItemHtml($_item) ?>
            </tbody>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
 <?php $_giftMessage = $this->helper('Magento\GiftMessage\Helper\Message')->getGiftMessage($_order->getGiftMessageId()); ?>
        <?php if ($_giftMessage): ?>
            <br />
            <table class="message-gift">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <h3><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Gift Message for this Order') ?></h3>
                        <strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('From:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getSender()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('To:') ?></strong> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getRecipient()) ?>
                        <br /><strong><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Message:') ?></strong>
                        <br /><?= $block->escapeHtml($_giftMessage->getMessage()) ?>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Obviously, I receive this error message:

> Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getGiftMessageId()

since my block does not have the method `getOrder`.

But if I try to copy `getOrder` method from `Magento\Sales\Block\Order\Items`:

```php
    /**
     * Retrieve current order model instance
     *
     * @return \Magento\Sales\Model\Order
     */
    public function getOrder()
    {
        return $this->_coreRegistry->registry('current_order');
    }
```

with `__construct` part

```php
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param array $data
     * @param \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory|null $itemCollectionFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        array $data = [],
        \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory $itemCollectionFactory = null
    ) {
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        $this->itemCollectionFactory = $itemCollectionFactory ?: \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
            ->get(\Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Item\CollectionFactory::class);
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }
```

it still shows an error that order object in null. What am I doing wrong? Or how can I obtain order object in my case? Thanks.